# Creating custom visual component for Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, button, xamarin, components

I am developing an app that has a `StackLayout` and the first visual component of the on top of the page has to have something that looks, feels and acts like a button but that is customize with a glyph on the left side, a header-text in the middle top-left next to the glyph, and an information text under the header text.

I have attached a visual demonstration of what I'm looking for below.

I have also tried to find information on Google about how to achieve this but honestly I don't even know what terms to search for.

I've tried `panel`, `custom visual component` and much more, but I can't seem to find anything that fits the description that I'm looking for.

Note: I'm new to Xamarin and C#.

Example:

[image]

Comment: https://blog.falafel.com/creating-reusable-xaml-user-controls-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @Jason I get many errors from that code example. It seems to be out of date.

Comment: The basic concept should still apply.  You just use a ContentView to compose the UI you want, then you can re-use that in your app as a custom control.

Comment: @Jason and the contentview is like a canvas that contains children I'm assuming? Could I make ContentView clickable as well so the whole area of ContentView becomes a button?

Comment: Yes.  You can use gestures to add a Tap gesture to your View.

Comment: @Jason But `ContentView` can only contain a single element, could a `RelativeView` be used as well?

Comment: You would put a Layout inside the ContentView to contain your child elements

Comment: You are going to need a few custom classes.  ClickableImage class that extends image and has a TapGestureRecognizer (used for your left and right images so they act like buttons).  Class that extends Grid that will be your main container.  That class should have 3 columns, 3 rows.  Put clickable image in first and third column, span all rows.  Put your three labels in middle column in each row.  Then just create bindable properties for your image sources and the text of each label.